# In electron, how to set callback at dialog.showMessageBox for 6.0.0 version?

Tags: callback, dialog, arguments, electron, refactoring

I upgrade the electron version of developing program, from 5.0.0. to 6.0.0. But I found that the arguments of dialog.showMessageBox for 6.0.0 was changed. Previously I put callback info as one of argument, but I upgrade to 6.0.0, I do not know how to set callback info.
Can you tell me how to set up it?

Answer (score 0):

**dialog.showMessageBox** has been renamed to **dialog.showMessageBoxSync**. **dialog.showMessageBox** now returns a Promise.

Any existing call to dialog.showMessageBox will now return a Promise instead of a value. 
In plus users will need to change to **dialog.showMessageBoxSync** to return to the prior behavior, or modify their code to accept a Promise instead.

Please use **showMessageBox(options).then(response)** instead set **callback** at **showMessageBox**